# How to launch IE inPrivate browsing with Ruby and Watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, internet-explorer, watir

I need to launch the Watir IE browser inPrivate mode.
Chrome`s icognito mode can be launched fairly easily with:

```
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, switches: ['--incognito']
```

I tried this in IE, but it doesn`t work

```
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie, switches: ['-private']
```

I tried some of the indications here, but did not succeed
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

with

```
ie.forceCreateProcessApi with true value and ie.browserCommandLineSwitches with -private
```

Comment: The documentation indicates that you "need to pass 2 specific capabilities to driver: ie.forceCreateProcessApi with true value and ie.browserCommandLineSwitches with -private value. Be note that it will work only for InternetExplorer 8 and newer, and Windows Registry HKLM_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main path should contain key TabProcGrowth with 0 value".

Comment: Have you tried getting one of the other command line switches to work from here http://watir.com/guides/ie/ like ':initial_browser_url'? If you can get that to work, you should be able to set the create_process_api to true and the switch to --private

Comment: I tried pretty much everything you mentioned: the specific capabilities for inPrivate browsing mode do not work. @Alister Scott I tried sending the command key ctrl+shift+p to launch the private browsing window. However, switching to that window with `@browser.windows.last.use` or `@browser.window(title: `InPrivate`).use` does not work. It seems that the InPrivate window is not even recognized. `@browser.windows` is an array with 1 element (the initial webdriver window) instead of 2 (webdriver window + inPrivate) one. I`m honestly ready to give up on this topic.